# Similar entities in room database in android

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have three entities (VideoModel, AudioModel, and ImageModel) that have the same logic for deleting, inserting, etc. that is, the Dao classes are identical as well as the repository. What is the recommended way to avoid so much boilerplate code when using Room database in android?

The data is always fetched at the same time, so it occurred to me that I could create an entity that wraps all the models to save them together, so it would avoid all the boilerplate code, but when I get the data I'll have to fetch it and on insert, update, etc. . I would have to wrap them.

```
@Entity
public class MediaWrapperEntity {
    @Embedded
    private VideoModel videoModel;
    @Embedded
    private AudioModel audioModel;
    @Embedded
    private ImageModel imageModel;

    public VideoModel getVideoModel() {
        return videoModel;
    }

    public void setVideoModel(VideoModel videoModel) {
        this.videoModel = videoModel;
    }

    public AudioModel getAudioModel() {
        return audioModel;
    }

    public void setAudioModel(AudioModel audioModel) {
        this.audioModel = audioModel;
    }

    public ImageModel getImageModel() {
        return imageModel;
    }

    public void setImageModel(ImageModel imageModel) {
        this.imageModel = imageModel;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)